# Non floated div next to two floated divs

Tags: css

I have a container which has two children divs (toggle yellow background to see them) which are left floated. I wanted to add a third one (red colored) below those two, without any floating, but it stretches through all the container. Any ideas why?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/RrQff/2/

**HTML**

```
<center>
<div id='container'>
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div id='extra'>abc<div>       
<div>
</center>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {

    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:gray;
}

.big {
    height:350px;
   /* background-color:yellow;*/
}

#container > div:first-child {border-right:1px solid black;}

#container > div {
width:199px;
float:left;

}

#extra {

    background-color:red;
    width:80% !important;
    float:none !important;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `<center>`. Instead do `margin: 0 auto;` to center the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to the css of your `#extra` div, like so:

```
#extra {
    background-color:red;
    width:80% !important;
    float:none !important;
    margin-top:20px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS Clear:

```
#extra {
  clear: both;
  background-color:red;
  width:80% !important;
  float:none !important;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/RrQff/5/

Answer (score 0):

A better sollution would be to use display: inline-block for all 3 Divs or :

```
> #container{ position: relative;}
> #container .big:first {position: absolute; top: ... left: ...}
> #container div+div { top: ..left } $container #extra { position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the divs. Try doing this:

```
<center>
<div id='container'>
    <div class="big">div one (floated)</div>
    <div class="big">div two (floated)</div>
    <div class="clear" style="clear:both" />
    <div id='extra'>third div (which i want below floated ones)<div>        
<div>
</center>
```

Insert a clear:both div below the two floated divs